# PHP adodb COM recordset returning variant:__set_state for dates/times, how can I just get them as strings?

Tags: php, sql-server, adodb, variant

I'm accessing an mssql db in PHP and creating the connection as a new COM() object. My query runs perfectly fine. When I do the query in Microsoft SQL Server 2008, everything looks great, the dates/times show up in columns and are readable.

But when I run the same query and return the results in PHP, I go to iterate through the results like so:

```
$selected_fields = array("FS.fund_name", "M.media_id", "MT.media_type_name", "modified_date", "file_upload_date", "issued_date", "filename");
//query goes here
$record_set = new COM("ADODB.Recordset");
while(!$record_set->EOF){ //loop through query results and add to inline cache variable
  $temp_record = array();
  foreach($selected_fields as $fieldname){ //go through fields and add to array
      $fieldname_array = explode(".", $fieldname); //separate table and column
      $fieldname = $fieldname_array[sizeof($fieldname_array)-1];
      $temp_record[$fieldname] = $record_set->fields[$fieldname]->value;
  }
  print_r($temp_record);
  $rs_array[] = $temp_record;
  $record_set->movenext();
}
```

As I print each $temp_record, they end up looking like this:

```
Array ( [fund_name] => TEST [media_id] => 1001 [media_type_name] => 8937 Tax Forms [modified_date] => variant Object [file_upload_date] => variant Object [issued_date] => variant Object [filename] => form8937test.pdf )
```

So the dates are some kind of object, and I don't know how to access them in PHP. And when I go to save them as a cache file, they have this value:

```
variant::__set_state(array())
```

How can I retrive the date/time in a format that I can then manipulate using PHP? I want to filter them by year, and sort them by most recent.

Comment: According to [Variant Object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.variant.php) documentation, you should be able to access it by `$temp_record['modified_date']->value;` or `$val = (string)$temp_record['modified_date'];`

Comment: IT WORKS! All I had to do was cast it as a string. Thanks! Now - is there any way during my iteration that I can check to see if I need to cast it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Variant Object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.variant.php) documentation, you should be able to access it by

```
$temp_record['modified_date']->value;
```

or

```
$val = (string)$temp_record['modified_date'];
```

From the same doc:

> the variant is converted to a PHP value only when there is a direct
>   mapping between the types that would not result in a loss of
>   information. In all other cases, the result is returned as an instance
>   of the VARIANT class.

So to check if cast is needed, simply check if you have an object of `Variant` class:

```
if (is_object($var) && $var instanceof Variant) {
    $val = (string)$var;
} else {
    $val = $var;
}
```